Why do numerical eigenvector computations turn out different compared to symbolic formulas?
The following $A \vec x=\lambda \vec x$

should have 4 eigenvector solutions of the form

Setting $c=1, m=1, p_x=1, p_y=1, p_z=1$, the eigenvalues should be
$$\lambda = \pm 2$$
while the corresponding eigenvectors be
$$u^{(1)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1+i}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$u^{(2)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \frac{1-i}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$u^{(3)} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1+i}{3} & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$u^{(4)} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1-i}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
But numerical computation (using math.js) instead yields

which have the correct eigenvalues, but very different-looking eigenvectors.
Is there any chance the above numerical versus symbolic eigenvectors are actually identical (e.g. by taking linear combinations)?

I don't know about this specific case, but there's a whole field of study around this. The very (very) basic answer is that computers have limited precision which leads to rounding error which builds up since computers solve lots of problems through a large number of operations.

Why use $A$. and $v$ at the start when the images clearly use $E$ and $u?$

@ThomasAndrews thank you, I wrote the title using standard symbols so answers may be purely about linear algebra (instead of what E and u means)

The eigenvectors in the book are not normalized. Numerical routines tend to give normalized eigenvectors when possible (e.g. when the matrix is hermitian).

Moreover, since the eigenvalues are doubly degenerate there is a freedom of choice in the eigenspaces.

Your second numerical e vector is a rescaling of your first calculated one. You should really say which calculated vector goes with which e value.

@Paul you are right, I have edited what the symbolic eigenvectors should be. A detailed derivation for the eigenvector formula is given in https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node488.html

@lcv the missing 0 entries from the numerical answer is what confuses me... Why are the 0's missing if it's just normalization issue?

It's not only (necessarily) normalization. You can also take linear combinations.

Eigenvectors are not unique even symbolically.

@CroCo thank you, yes indeed! Could you help confirm that the span of the eigenvectors in both numerical and symbolic versions above are truly identical (since the eigenvectors are linearly independent in both versions)?
